# Requery Report based on Form fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report, DepositsReport, where the user can specify a date range and a deposit type to display, by entering them on a form (called DepositReportOptions).  Once the form is submitted, it runs the report, which is based on a query.

Among other things, the report displays DepositDate and DepositType.

In the query the report is based on, the criteria for DepositDate are:

```
Between [Forms]![DepositReportOptions]![Date1] And [Forms]![DepositReportOptions]![Date2]
```

The criterion for DepositType is:

```
[Forms]![DepositReportOptions]![DepositType]
```

The report works just fine, but I am running into issues when I try to refresh the report.  You can click on a record on the report, which opens it up in a form so you can edit the record.  When you get back to report, I'd like it to refresh.  I have a refresh button on the report, that just has   `DoCmd.Requery` behind it.  This is making Access pop up windows that prompt me to enter Date1, Date2, and DepositType again.  I want it to use those same values (that I initially provided on the DepositReportOptions form) when it requeries, so you don't get prompted to enter them again.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Is the `DepositReportOptions` form closed when you requery the report?

Comment: @HansUp Yes, the form closes when you click OK.

Comment: I have no idea where you click OK.  But my thought is don't close `DepositReportOptions` where you were closing it before.  Instead you can minimize or hide it, and then those text box values should be accessible when you requery the report.

Comment: Using `Me.Refresh` throws an error.

Comment: Right, `Refresh` triggers a compile error, *"Method or data member not found"*.  Use `Me.Requery` in your report's "refresh" button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.  Using `Me.Visible = False` on the form keeps the values there, allowing you to run the report, edit records, and refresh the report, using those same values.  When you get back to the form, the values are still there, which actually could be a "feature", making the fields sticky.